# How do I blur everything by focusing on the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

using Jquery/javascript

Is it: $(document).focus()?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The `.focus()` method on a jQuery-wrapped element will bind to the `onfocus` event if a function is passed as the first parameter, or trigger attached event handlers with no parameter.

I'm not sure why you're trying to do what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to blur the currently active element, no matter what element it is, you can use:

```js
document.activeElement.blur();
```

This isn't advised though, as doing so will reset the tabbing order and potentially annoy keyboard-navigating users.

Comment: Best put a check in like `if ('activeElement' in document)` first, as it's not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @bobince: Added it as a precautionary measure. `activeElement` is supported in the latest versions of Firefox, Opera, WebKit and IEs 6 through 8 and is also part of the HTML5 spec, so hopefully it will be widely supported anyway.

Comment: [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement) is an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) type, not [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), so it doesn't technically support `blur()`. TypeScript will not allow this to be used.

Comment: a use for this would be closing an overlay with an input, simply you don't want to keep it focused after closing the overlay,  because you will type without understanding why it is

Comment: @vaindil in that case, you can just do `(document.activeElement as HTMLElement)`. I don't think there are any elements that can take focus that don't have a `focus()` method.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE:** In Typescript you should just cast to `HTMLElement` like this:

```
(document.activeElement as HTMLElement).blur();
// or
(<HTMLElement>document.activeElement).blur();
```

Original answer is below.

---

The accepted answer won't work in TypeScript because [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement) is an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) type, not [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), so it doesn't technically support `blur()`. The below method is kind of hacky but it works properly.

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45312145):

```
const tmp = document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(tmp);
tmp.focus();
document.body.removeChild(tmp);
```

Comment: Isn't `removeChild()` missing an argument?

Comment: It is, just fixed and also added a note that you should just cast to `HTMLElement`.

Comment: it works om typescript if you declare 
const activeElement: any = document.activeElement; seems less hacky to me

Answer (score 1):

`$().method()` fires the listeners associated with that method. If you need to call functions on dom elements, index the jQuery object.

i.e.

```
$(document)[0].focus()
```

Although why you wouldn't just use `document.focus` is probably a question worth answering.

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to remove the focus on any form field element you can use this:

```
$(':focus').blur();
```

If you don't have jQuery, you can use plain JavaScript:

```
let elem = document.querySelector(':focus');
if(elem ) {
  elem .blur();
}
```