# javascript - unfocus a textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a mobile template with a login form which is ajax / url hash based browsing. If on an iphone a user clicks the "go" button on the iphone keyboard the ajax authenticates / logs them in and then loads the next page inside another div and hides the current login form div.

The problem is, on an iphone the keyboard is still popped up. Is there anyway to unfocus a textbox element via javascript?

Comment: http://web-design.blogs.webucator.com/files/2010/08/onFocusTShirt.gif :-)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use the `blur()` method or try setting the focus on another element like a link.

Comment: is there no other way? I've tried setting the focus on a div and that didn't work

Comment: well there is the `blur()` method

Comment: `document.activeElement.blur();` worked perfectly for my case.

Comment: I had to use `event.target.parentNode.blur()` in my case, the focus was further up; it even works multiple parents up the hierarchy. Just in case anyone lands here with this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 30):

This is what I used when `.blur()` didn't want to be my friend

```
function blurAll(){
 var tmp = document.createElement("input");
 document.body.appendChild(tmp);
 tmp.focus();
 document.body.removeChild(tmp);
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, and just what I was looking for. I like this answer because it's self-contained and does just exactly this one thing, and leaves no clutter.

Comment: Tremendous solution.

Comment: This was the only one that worked, but unfortunately it scrolls the page to the very bottom.

Comment: Haven't tested this, but setting `tmp.style.position = "fixed"` would probably prevent any scrolling.

Answer (score 10):

If you only want to blur something without a target, you can call `blur()` on [activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement):

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

Comment: For Typescript
`if (document.activeElement instanceof HTMLElement) document.activeElement.blur();`

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of element.disabled parameter in javascript.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText">

<p>Click the button to unfocus the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Unfocus input</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("myText").focus();
function myFunction() {
 
   document.getElementById("myText").disabled = true;    
    document.getElementById("myText").disabled = false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have easy access to the specific element that you want to blur, there is a slightly hacky way you can implement "blur all" functionality.

Just add the following HTML somewhere on your page:

```
<input id="blur-hack" type="text" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
```

Then this JS will unfocus anything currently focused:

```
document.getElementById("blur-hack").focus();
```

Note that for the inline HTML styling, we can't do `display: none` or else you can't focus on it. `position` and `opacity` will adequately remove the element from the flow - you could also use margins to shove it way off the page, etc.

Comment: or you could just set `height` to 0

Answer (score 2):

This will maintain scroll, and not cause any flash of a element

```
resetFocus () {
    let scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    let body = document.body;

    let tmp = document.createElement('input');
    tmp.style.opacity = 0;
    body.appendChild(tmp);
    tmp.focus();
    body.removeChild(tmp);
    body.scrollTop = scrollTop;
}
```

based on @skygoo's solution

Answer (score 2):

Building on the solution from @shygoo - this translates well into TypeScript!

```
export function unfocus(): any {
    const tmp: HTMLInputElement => document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(tmp);
    tmp.focus();
    document.body.removeChild(tmp);
}
```

Some notes...

1. It is of type `any` so that it's compatible with AngularJS's `$timeout` service, even though it never actually returns anything.
2. `tmp` is constant since it never changes during the lifetime of the function call.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with **classNames**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('formButtons').blur()
```

and the **solution** was Array.from()

```
const btns = Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName('formButtons') ) 
if (btns && btns.length) {
 // go over let i in btns and 
 // btns[i].blur()
}
```