# Do do I unfocus from an input in Vue.JS 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Let's suppose I have an input like this:

```
<input type="text" v-model="x" ref="refInput">
```

If I want this input to focus programmatically, I can do:

```
this.$refs['refInput'].focus()
```

**Is there a way to make the input lose the focus programmatically?**

I tried this without success:

```
this.$refs['refInput'].unfocus()  // This does not work!
```

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075057/javascript-unfocus-a-textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a simple JavaScript question. You focus on an input and leave focus with blur. What you need to do is to run the blur function.

example:

```
this.$refs.refInput.blur()
```